# Google analytics regular expression

Tags: regex, google-analytics

I'm trying to set up a Google Analytics goal url regular expression to match:

Any number of any characters followed by "first-login?" followed by any number of any characters.

Examples:

- /user/452/first-login?uid=452
- /bob-smith/first-login?fish=tuna

Seems simple, but I'm a total noob at regex. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a simple `indexOf` to search for the `first-login?` substring in the URL.

If that is not possible, the Perl compatible regex below will match a URL that contains `first-login?` as substring. You may need to add separator character or string escape depending on the language you are using.

```
^.*first-login\?.*$
```

(Note: answer edited to match the question)

Comment: What is a Perl Compatible Regular Expression compatible regex? :-)

Comment: This regex works everywhere so you could strip "x compatible" etirely ;-)

Comment: @JanDvorak: I have some doubt about that. I'd rather keep it there to be on the safe side.

Comment: Thanks! Works great. Without the slash (I included a slash initially, but changed my question later) it's just ^.*first-login\?.*$